# How to write formula of a concave hyperbola

Tags: functions, graphing-functions

I started with plotting this equation of a convex hyperbola:

```
y = 2/x
```

Which of course looks like this (I'm only interested in 1st quadrant):
[image]

Now, I want to plot the same function, but have it flipped about, such that it becomes concave. What is the formula for that? It should look concave, like this:

[image]

```
y = ???
```

**Note:** I made these graphs myself, don't scrutinize them too much!

Comment: y = k + 1/(x-c)

Comment: @GNUSupporter8964民主女神地下教會 Ok, hmm, what's k? is k = x or is it a constant like c?

Comment: They are constants.  You may try Desmos, which enables graph sharing.

Comment: @GNUSupporter8964民主女神地下教會 Just to double check, to flip my example equation `y=2/x` to concave, I would input: `y=2+1/(x-2)`?

Comment: You can check that on a graphical calculator like Desmos to be reassured of your observation.  Actually, that would give the required shape, but I won't call that a "flipping" of 1/x.  That's in fact a translation and clipping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$y=\frac{2}{x}$ is its own reflection across the line $y=-x$ (it is already 'concave' for $x\leq0$). You only need to shift the viewing window to the lower-left quadrant or translate the function right and up by some suitable distance.

The curve $y-a=f(x-b)$ is the translation of the curve $y=f(x)$ upwards by $a$ and to the right by $b$. This is why GNUSupporter8964民主女神地下教會 commented $y=k+\frac{1}{x-c}$. If you want to shift the graph upwards by $k$ and to the right by $c$, you would solve for $y$ in the equation $y-k=f(x-c)$ where $f(x)=your\ function=\frac{2}{x}$.

$$f(x)=\frac{2}{x};\quad y=f(x);\quad y-k=f(x-c)\implies y=\frac{2}{x-c}+k$$

Comment: thanks, that helps a bit. Would you mind sharing what values I should put for c and k to translate the hyperbola up to the correct position? I tried tinkering with it using wolframalpha. You can see I didn't quite shift it to the right place: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%3D2%2F(x-2)%2B2. When I try plugging in larger constants, all that changes is the function gets more stretched out. I'm not sure why, hopefully I'm not doing something wrong.

Comment: The graph isn't being stretched out, Wolfram Alpha scales the viewing window automatically when you plot a function. The values for $c$ and $k$ depend on the size of your viewing window and where it's centered. If your viewing window is $x=0\ldots u,y=0\ldots v$, then you'll want to have $c=u$ and $k=v$.